# nodejs cluster different TLS Session handling

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, ssl

What  am I trying to do: create multiple TLS servers that listen on same port. Each TLS server has different set of certificates and should only allow certain set of clients. For example, first TLS server should allow Client X and not Client Y. Second TLS server should allow Client Y and not Client X.

Issue that I am having is Client Y and X both connect only with first TLS server. TLS certificates used are different for each client are signed by different TLS servers, but they tend to connect only to first TLS server.

Would appreciate any thoughts on this issue.

Comment: do they have different domains or is everything the same other than the certificates?

Comment: Idea was to use same domain and differentiate users depending on server that signs certificate for it.

Answer (score 0):

That setup just isn't going to work. The [cluster API](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) lets multiple workers share a port, but there is no intelligence about which worker gets allocated to which requests. If there isn't a lot of load, it's entirely possible that only one worker will receive all the requests.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you think about it, this kind of setup doesn't make sense. If you have different certificates, then there is just no way for a TLS session to be setup successfully. It would be like trying to bind multiple SSL certificates to the same IP.

The only way I could see this working is if each of those different certificates corresponds with a different hostname. In that case, you could try using SNI as documented at http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/tls.html#tls.connect. However, each worker process would still need to access the same pool of certificates.

Comment: Thanks Rohan for your response. Yeah with some experimentation I came to same conclusion on worker thread that receives message is random. I am going to ahead with SNI solution and rely on servername to handle different certificates.

Comment: @Janon Sounds good. One thing I would be wary of with SNI is browser support. Older browsers and some versions of Android don't support SNI. Might be worth looking into the details.